# Jmeter and java.net.NoRouteToHostException while sending a file via REST

Tags: java, docker, routes, jmeter, docker-swarm

I'm running into a very strange problem and I don't seem to be able to find an easy solution anywhere.

I'm running some tests in JMeter that are testing file sending via HTTP with a REST API that is contained in my application which is dockerized.

The problem seems to be like this:

- I launch the test, it works.
- I launch it again, and I get a java.net.NoRouteToHostException in the HTTP Request part.
- I launch it again, and it works.
- I launch it again, and I get the error.

And so on. It seems to give me this error in a yes-no-yes-no pattern which makes it impossible for my tests to run in a sequence as the first test works, the second fails, the third works and so on.

The port I'm using is forwarded by Docker 8082->8080 and the test is set to connect to localhost (I have tried with 127.0.0.1 and with my LAN IP and I get the same results).

JMeter is running natively in Centos 7, only my application is dockerized.

Any clue? I'm completely lost.

Here is the trace:

```
Thread Name: Test Iteration 1-1
Sample Start: 2018-04-09 14:33:01 CEST
Load time: 3006
Connect Time: 0
Latency: 0
Size in bytes: 1898
Headers size in bytes: 0
Body size in bytes: 1898
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 1
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""): text
Response code: Non HTTP response code: java.net.NoRouteToHostException
Response message: Non HTTP response message: No route to host (Host unreachable)
Response headers:
HTTPSampleResult fields:
ContentType: 
DataEncoding: null
```

Thank you.

Comment: you launch your docker every time?

Comment: No, the docker container is loaded prior to executing Jmeter, and it stays up until I finish my testing campaign or until I don't need it anymore.

Comment: do you have load balancer that may route to different host?

Comment: not intentionally and not that I'm aware of, any clue on how to check that?

Comment: By the way, docker is running in swarm mode, could that be the problem?

Comment: I don't know it but wee http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-distributed-load-testing-using-docker-in-aws/

Comment: my intention is not to distribute JMeter, I only have one Jmeter instance, what I could have is several instances of my application which is dockerized

Comment: As a clarification if it helps anyone, it seems to be a bug in the load balancer in Docker Swarm. If I scale my application to 3 instances, it works 3 times in a row and then it fails. I have tested this several times and I can confirm the JMeter test works as many times as instances I have, then fails, then works again in a row until it fails again.

Comment: Do you mean https://github.com/docker/swarm/issues/1814 ?

Comment: Not really, my JMeter is not distributed and my application is running in Swarm mode but currently in only one machine, the references are to localhost, not to a subnet IP. This looks like a bug in Docker's load balancer for Swarm mode.